# split columns, extract numbers, and subtract difference

Tags: python, pandas, replace, split

Community! I have this following df

```
data = {'exp_lvl': ['5-10 yrs', '3-5 yrs', '1-3 Years']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

my goal is something like:

[image]

my approach is to 1. replace values , 2. split, 3. append to list, 4. build columns from the appended lists. However i'm stuck in the last step and maybe there is a easier way to approach

thansk so much!!!

Comment: Why do you need pandas at all?  Just to make it print pretty?  I would do all of my text processing before going into pandas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was not hard.  Just mechanical.  Did you make any effort?

```
data = {'exp_lvl': ['5-10 yrs', '3-5 yrs', '1-3 Years']}

data['first'] = []
data['second'] = []
data['difference'] = []
for row in data['exp_lvl']:
    parts = [int(i) for i in row.split(' ')[0].split('-')]
    data['first'].append( parts[0] )
    data['second'].append( parts[1] )
    data['difference'].append( parts[1]-parts[0] )

print(data)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
C:\tmp>python x.py
{'exp_lvl': ['5-10 yrs', '3-5 yrs', '1-3 Years'], 'first': [5, 3, 1], 'second': [10, 5, 3], 'difference': [5, 2, 2]}
     exp_lvl  first  second  difference
0   5-10 yrs      5      10           5
1    3-5 yrs      3       5           2
2  1-3 Years      1       3           2

C:\tmp>
```

Comment: ohh, I just didn´t know about the "trick" data['first'] = [] to compute values. I was getting stuck to transform a list into a column of df!  thank you really much, Tim!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way:

```
df.join(df['exp_lvl'].str.extractall(r'(\d+)')[0]
 .unstack()
 .rename({0:'first',1:'second'},axis=1)
 .astype(float)
 .assign(diff = lambda x: x['second'] - x['first']))
```

or

```
(df.join(
    df['exp_lvl'].str.extract(r'(?P<first>\d+)-(?P<second>\d+)')
    .astype(int)
    .assign(difference = lambda x: x['second'] - x['first'])))
```

Output:

```
     exp_lvl  first  second  difference
0   5-10 yrs      5      10           5
1    3-5 yrs      3       5           2
2  1-3 Years      1       3           2
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Could you provide the intermediate output as well, to explain the `str.extractall[0]` magic parameter

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas `str.split` to construct column `first` and `second`. Next, compute to get column `different`

```
df[['first', 'second']] = df.exp_lvl.str.split('-| ').str[:2].tolist()
df['difference'] = df['second'].astype(int) - df['first'].astype(int)

Out[103]:
     exp_lvl first second  difference
0   5-10 yrs     5     10           5
1    3-5 yrs     3      5           2
2  1-3 Years     1      3           2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
df[['first', 'second']] = df.exp_lvl.str.extract(r'(\d+)-(\d+)')
df['difference'] = df['second'].astype(int) - df['first'].astype(int)
```